# Accepting an answer on a game-recommendation question

Tags: discussion, questions, game-recommendation

I've recently started a [game-recommendation question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50041/9328) and have received some very good suggestions from the community.  I'm ready to try a few of them, but there's a more immediate problem that needs addressing.

These questions are all very good...but I'm not sure what the proceedure is for accepting an answer on this type of question.

Any or all of these answers that recommend a system are good recommendations, but no single answer is necessarily the 'right' answer.  Many are very good, and as such are getting upvoted for their high quality and accuracy, but I the question asker am not sure how to determine which good answer is most worthy of being 'accepted'.

What is the usual practice for accepting an answer on a game-recommendation question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You accept the answer that is most useful to you. If no answer is useful to you then you probably want to edit your question or post a comment on it to specify what about the current answers does not fulfill your requirements so that answers can be more tailored.

Never feel like you have to accept an answer if you do not feel your question has been answered.

As an aside:
Upvotes and Downvotes are what the community feels is a good or bad answers. Feel free to ignore them when you select your accepted answer; It is your question after all.

Answer (score 10):

As Mourdos said, you accept the answer most useful to you. (In fact in general I strongly agree with his answer here.) You're under no time pressure or obligation to accept an answer. What you accept and why is up to you.

However, for a game recommendation, it would probably be logical to accept the answer providing the game that you find works best for your purposes. I recommend trying them out before accepting an answer - this means you pick the system that works well, not the one that looks good but might fail to deliver when you try it out. After all, you don't need to accept an answer anytime soon. You have time to experiment first.

If no answers are good, you don't have to accept any of them. You may wish to refine your requirements as Mourdos said, or wait it out if there's nothing more to say.

Comment: Anecdote: I once accepted a game-rec answer on the merits of a single session, but after the next session I discovered that it wasn't actually as useful as I'd thought. Nearly a year later the question remains open, with no currently accepted answer.

Comment: And of course you can also un-accept if you try out a recommendation and it doesn’t work out as well as you’d hoped.